# How access a value of a text inside a form in a post route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a form with a post method, and I need to send the values of two fields in the form to my post route.

This is the HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    <h2>My Form</h2>
        <legend name="legend">I NEED PUSH THIS VALUE</legend>


        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

        <button id="send" type="submit">Send infos</button>
</form>
```

This way i can access the value of the name label using req.body.name, simple. Now my question:

how access the value of the legend tag?? [I NEED PUSH THIS VALUE].

```
app.post(routerName, function (req, res) { 
  var data = req.body;
});
```

Comment: Either submit the form via ajax and add that value on, or add a hidden input with that value to your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, you can't.

Browsers do not submit the content of legend elements (and there is no reason for them to do so: legends are not user input).

If you want to add additional data to a form, then use a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="legend" value="HERE YOU GO">
```

Comment: I think about this alternative, but I think it could influence in SEO.

Comment: Anyone.. thanks very much @Quentin.. Congrats, 356k, you are crazy hahahaha

Answer (score -1):

You can only access values posted with a form: input, checkboxes, dropdowns, etc. Legends and label values can't be accessed.

Use a hidden field, use JavaScript to pass the value to the field and then post it.

Comment: Nobody dares to explain the reason?

Comment: @bad_boy lol....it was my mistake for making a false assumption. My earlier answer assumed that the OP was asking how to retrieve, on the server, the value posted by a text input. I realized my mistake after seeing that the question was about labels and legends. So, I edited it. Thanks for the upvote :).